# Attempt to access dataframe column displays "<bound method NDFrame.xxx..."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I create DataFrame object in Jupyter notebook:

```
data = {'state':['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
       'year':[2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001],
       'pop':[1.5, 2.0, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
frame = DataFrame(data)
```

When I'm extracting column 'year', it's ok:

```
In [30]: frame.year
Out[30]: 0    2000
         1    2001
         2    2002
         3    2000
         4    2001
         Name: year, dtype: int64
```

But when I'm extracting column 'pop' (frame.pop), result is:

```
Out[31]:
<bound method NDFrame.pop of    pop   state  year
0  1.5    Ohio  2000
1  2.0    Ohio  2001
2  3.6    Ohio  2002
3  2.4  Nevada  2000
4  2.9  Nevada  2001>
```

Why the result is not the same as for "frame.year"?

Comment: [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is a reserved method of dataframe, instead use `frame['pop']`

Comment: As `pop` is reserved, try changing the column name to simplify the use of your DF. For instance `frame.rename(columns={'pop':'population'})`

Comment: Use `frame['pop']` instead of `frame.pop` to avoid name-collisions with builtins; also necessary if the name contains whitespace. Per @cs95's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is a dataframe level function. The takeaway here is try to avoid using the `.` accessor to access columns. There are many dataframe attributes and functions that might clash with your column names, in which case the `.` will invoke those instead of your columns.

You want to use the `[..]` dict accessor instead:

```
frame['pop']
0    1.5
1    2.0
2    3.6
3    2.4
4    2.9
Name: pop, dtype: float64
```

---

If you want to use `pop`, you *can*. This is how:

```
frame.pop('pop') 
0    1.5
1    2.0
2    3.6
3    2.4
4    2.9
Name: pop, dtype: float64

frame
    state  year
0    Ohio  2000
1    Ohio  2001
2    Ohio  2002
3  Nevada  2000
4  Nevada  2001
```

Do note that this modifies the original dataframe, so don't do it unless you're trying to remove columns.

Comment: Just had this issue. Apparently I used nunique instead of nunique()

Answer (score 2):

The way I am using ..`.eval`

```
frame.eval('pop')
Out[108]: 
0    1.5
1    2.0
2    3.6
3    2.4
4    2.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: why use eval when you can use dict accessor

Comment: @Bharathshetty Just because my habit .. I using `query` and `eval` the most .

Answer (score 0):

`pop` is a method of `pandas.DataFrame`. You need to use `frame['pop']`